# Can I access a non-existent or non-valid css property with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There are 2 parts to  this question:

1. If I define a CSS transition and try to access it with jQuery's `.css()` method, can I reliably assume that if the browser I'm running on does not support that CSS property it will always return `undefined`?
2. If I **DON'T** define a CSS property and try to access it with jQuery's `.css()` method, can I reliably assume that it will always return `undefined`?

Comment: I would say, try it and see what happens.

Comment: Agreed. Is it currently returning undefined for you?

Comment: For your second part the answer is no.... if the property isn't defined on the CSS file it will return the default value defined for some properties.

Comment: @Danko I stand corrected. Thank you sir.

Comment: Just make the right test look at console here on Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/5L3zu/6/

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is, #1. yes. #2. No.

The long answer is: #1. yes, you can make up a classname to test this, for example:

```
browser-foo: blue;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/32dzN/1/

If you haven't already, check out Modernizr. They provide excellent feature detection, I believe they put it into a DOM element off the screen if I recall correctly.

As for #2, that's not how it works at all. Because there are computed styles, as well as defined styles. For example, if you try to get the opacity of an element that you haven't set opacity on, it will return as 1.

Comment: If you see the fiddle on my comment you can know for #1 isn't always undefined...actually is the default defined for that property try it wiht transition and you'll see

Comment: Thanks Danko. I have looked at your fiddle, and you are retrieving a border-radius after applying a moz-border-radius.Which is not what the question is asking. If you re-read part #1, it says, what if I define a css property that the browser doesn't support, and then try to retrieve THAT property. Not the assumed property, which is what you have demonstrated. This is how his question is worded: http://jsfiddle.net/5L3zu/8/